# Wordpress - wrong serialized value on update_post_meta

Tags: wordpress, serialization

I'm trying to update post meta with serialized value over update_post_meta() function.

The value that i need to store is `yes`.
So with `serialize(array('yes'))` Im getting `a:1:{i:0;s:3:"yes";}` and thats fine.

However after running update_post_meta(), like:

```
update_post_meta(55, 'my_key', 'a:1:{i:0;s:3:"yes";}')
```

I get value `s:20:"a:1:{i:0;s:3:"yes";}";` in my database. Notice the difference.

Why is this happening and how to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function update_post_meta will automatically serialize an array passed into it. So you don't need to do the first serialization. Just pass the array directly, and give that a shot. I don't honestly know why it would try to serialize that string that you're passing, but I'm betting that directly passing the array will solve your problem.